# Need some advice on how to manage multiple income sources

Tags: united-states, taxes, accounting, software

I need some advice on how to manage multiple income sources.

I am a programmer/entrepreneur that has started a couple of side businesses online and just need some help.

Here are all my income sources:

- W2 day job - full time salary position - programmer
- 2 online websites that sell services - each with a different business partner
- 1099 contract position for local company - part time
- various online low income sources like fiverr.com and usertesting.com that pay me through paypal.

I'd like to know if there is an online accounting software that I could manage all of these income sources from one account that would also let me give access to my business partners for the specific online website businesses.  OR, should I go a different route?  I only started actually making money from the other stuff this year besides my day job so now I need to actually figure out my accounting/tax plan.

Any/all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

-rj

Answer (score 2):

If you're good with numbers and understand basic principles of accounting, I suggest using [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) - free and open-source accounting software which will provide for all your needs and more.

If you're not so comfortable with self-service, many tax preparers also provide bookkeeping services. It can cost somewhere from $50/hour, and you should shop around and also look for references. The bookkeeper doesn't have to be the one to do your taxes, but it will probably make it easier on you to have the same person do all of it.